# Recursive subtraction from two separate tables to fill in historical data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two datasets hosted in Snowflake with social media follower counts by day. The main table we will be using going forward (follower_counts) shows follower counts by day:

[image: follower_counts]

This table is live as of 4/4/2020 and will be updated daily. Unfortunately, I am unable to get historical data in this format. Instead, I have a table with historical data (follower_gains) that shows net follower gains by day for several accounts:

[image: follower_gains]

Ideally - I want to take the follower_count value from the minimum date in the current table (follower_counts) and subtract the sum of gains (organic + paid gains) for each day, until the minimum date of the follower_gains table, to fill in the follower_count historically. In addition, there are several accounts with data in these tables, so it would need to be grouped by account. It should look like this:

[image: ideal_table]

I've only gotten as far as unioning these two tables together, but don't even know where to start with looping through these rows:

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT
  account_id,
  date,
  organizational_entity,
  organizational_entity_type,
  vanity_name,
  localized_name,
  localized_website,
  organization_type,
  total_followers_count,
  null AS paid_follower_gain,
  null AS organic_follower_gain,
  account_name,
  last_update
FROM follower_counts
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
account_id,
  date,
  organizational_entity,
  organizational_entity_type,
  vanity_name,
  localized_name,
  localized_website,
  organization_type,
  null AS total_followers_count,
  organic_follower_gain,
  paid_follower_gain,
  account_name,
  last_update
  FROM follower_gains)
SELECT
a.account_id,
a.date,
a.organizational_entity,
a.organizational_entity_type,
a.vanity_name,
a.localized_name,
a.localized_website,
a.organization_type,
a.total_followers_count,
a.organic_follower_gain,
a.paid_follower_gain,
a.account_name,
a.last_update
FROM a 
ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Changed `union` to `union all` and added `not exists` to remove duplicates. Made changes per the comments.

NOTE: Please make sure you don't post images of the tables. It's difficult to recreate your scenario to write a correct query. Test this solution and update so that I can make modifications if necessary.

You don't `loop` through in SQL because its not a procedural language. The operation you define in the query is performed for all the rows in a table.

```
with cte as (SELECT a.account_id,
              a.date,
              a.organizational_entity,
              a.organizational_entity_type,
              a.vanity_name,
              a.localized_name,
              a.localized_website,
              a.organization_type,
              (a.follower_count - (b.organic_gain+b.paid_gain)) AS follower_count,
              a.account_name,
              a.last_update,
              b.organic_gain,
              b.paid_gain
       FROM follower_counts a
       JOIN follower_gains b ON a.account_id = b.account_id
       AND b.date < (select min(date) from 
       follower_counts c where a.account.id = c.account_id) 
       )
    SELECT b.account_id,
          b.date,
          b.organizational_entity,
          b.organizational_entity_type,
          b.vanity_name,
          b.localized_name,
          b.localized_website,
          b.organization_type,
          b.follower_count,
          b.account_name,
          b.last_update,
          b.organic_gain,
          b.paid_gain
    FROM cte b
    UNION ALL
     SELECT a.account_id,
           a.date,
           a.organizational_entity,
           a.organizational_entity_type,
           a.vanity_name,
           a.localized_name,
           a.localized_website,
           a.organization_type,
           a.follower_count,
           a.account_name,
           a.last_update,
           NULL as organic_gain,
           NULL as paid_gain
    FROM follower_counts a where not exists (select 1 from 
    follower_gains c where a.account_id = c.account_id AND a.date = c.date)
```

Comment: Thanks, Django. The only issue here is that the follower_gains table is still being updated daily (sorry I didn't mention this in the original post). Therefore, I'm unable to consistently subtract that total from total_followers, or else I will always have the same number. I'm wondering if there is a way we can only subtract organic+paid gain from total_followers if b.date < min(a.date) - partitioned by account_id.

Comment: @BrandonThomson Please check my updated answer. Is that what you mean? Just a piece of advice, you should not be doing this calculation on a continuously changing table. Sounds like you're trying to build OLAP solution on OLTP table.

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't giving me what I need. This will need to act like a rolling_subtraction. I'd like to take the minimum total_followers_count and subtract organic gain + paid gain for each day in the dataset of followers_gain. So if the first total_followers value is 10, and the gain the day before was 2, then that day's follower count would be 8, and if that day's gain was 2, then the day before would be 6. And so on.

Comment: Hey @django-unchained - It seems like a subquery using OVER and PARTITION can help get me where I need to be. But I can't quite figure out how. I added this to your existing query (in the top section of the query - cte) but it isn't quite yielding the proper results
 (SELECT d.date
              FROM improvado.improvado.linkedin_organic_followers_lifetime d
              ORDER BY d.date asc LIMIT 1) min_date,
             a.total_followers_count - SUM(b.organic_follower_gain + b.paid_follower_gain) OVER (partition by a.account_id ORDER BY a.date desc) net_followers...

any insight?

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this, instead of using the variable you can just wrap it another bracket and write at end `) AS FollowerGrowth`

```
DECLARE @FollowerGrowth INT = 
( SELECT total_followers_count 
  FROM follower_gains 
  WHERE AccountID = xx  ) 
- 
( SELECT TOP 1 follower_count 
  FROM follower_counts 
  WHERE AccountID = xx 
  ORDER BY date ASCENDING )
```